# pulling rows from a DF that have specific values: python

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to be able to pull specific columns from these values below. So for instance, if I want columns(species) that have a log mass of > 7.35 but < then 7.46, how would I code this. (this is a pandas DF)

```
     ID:       species:      log:     mass:                     ref:
    4676     mysticetus      8.00  100000000.0                   68  
    4683       physalus      7.85   70000000.0                   68  
    4720      marginata      7.51   32000000.0                   68  
    4684   novaeangliae      7.48   30000000.0                   68  
    4717       robustus      7.45   28500000.0                   68  
    4678      glacialis      7.36   23000000.0                   68  
    4677      australis      7.36   23000000.0                   68
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the dataframe like this:

```
df[(df['log'] > 7.35 ) & (df['log'] < 7.46)]['species']
```

Answer (score 0):

Masks allow you to do that sort of thing effectively:

```
In [15]: df.head()
Out[15]: 
    ID:      species:  log:        mass:  ref:
0  4676    mysticetus  8.00  100000000.0    68
1  4683      physalus  7.85   70000000.0    68
2  4720     marginata  7.51   32000000.0    68
3  4684  novaeangliae  7.48   30000000.0    68
4  4717      robustus  7.45   28500000.0    68

In [16]: df[(df['log:'] > 7.35) & (df['log:'] < 7.46)]
Out[16]: 
    ID:   species:  log:       mass:  ref:
4  4717   robustus  7.45  28500000.0    68
5  4678  glacialis  7.36  23000000.0    68
6  4677  australis  7.36  23000000.0    68

In [18]: df[(df['log:'] > 7.35) & (df['log:'] < 7.46)]['species:']
Out[18]: 
4     robustus
5    glacialis
6    australis
Name: species:, dtype: object
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc along with pandas series.between like this

```
df.loc[df['log:'].between(7.35, 7.46), 'species:']
```

Gives you

```
4     robustus
5    glacialis
6    australis
```